# How do i get rid of this error right operand of comma operator has no effect ( wunsued value)?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

i am having an issue with this code so all the tarif = x; is underlined when i run the program, but i don't see how i could solve this and exactly what is the error ? thank you for your help !

```
double saaq::Camion::tarificationAnnuelle() const
{
    double tarif;
    if(m_nbEssieux == 2 && m_poids >= 3001 && m_poids <= 4000)
    {
        tarif = 570,28;
    }
    if(m_nbEssieux == 2 && m_poids >= 4001)
    {
        tarif = 905,28;
    }
    if(m_nbEssieux == 4)
    {
        tarif = 2206,19;
    }
    if(m_nbEssieux == 5)
    {
        tarif = 2821,76;
    }
    if(m_nbEssieux >= 6)
    {
        tarif = 3729,76;
    }

    return tarif;

}
```

Comment: And if none of those conditions are true, the tarif could be a billion francs, no francs, -1000 francs, a different number every time the program is run, etc.  It's like playing roulette.  In other words, you should initialize your `tarif` variable.

Comment: The decimal separator in C/C++ is the dot (`.`), not the comma (`,`). The comma operator has a different meaning. Replace every use of `,` with `.`.

Answer (score 2):

It's an obvious typo when you write double constant:

```
tarif = 570,28;
```

should be

```
tarif = 570.28;
```

that applies to all other double assignments..

Also you should initialise your `tarif` variable,

```
double tarif = 0;
```

Comment: Maybe the OP comes from a country that uses the comma as the decimal point.  That's the probable reason for the error, and not really a typo.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that makes sense. Unit system is tricky

Comment: Not jumping into any debate, but if you think this is an obvious typo then it should be closed as a typo. There's a standard close reason for that use.

Comment: They shouldn’t initialize the variable unless it actually is required. Doing that will just make it impossible for the compiler to warn them about possible missing conditions and cause hard to find errors later.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen do you think it's required in this case? If none of the if-statement is correct, then what value should this function return?

Comment: @artm Most likely throw an error if a value can not be determined. Returning zero would just hide the problem unless it’s specifically handled on the outside and magic numbers are not great. Rather return NaN even if a value has to be returned.

Comment: @KenWhite that makes sense. Already voted to close due to typo..

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen well there is a "always initialise rule" unless the object has default constructor - for basic types there is no such default ctor so they should always be initialised.. https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es20-always-initialize-an-object

Comment: @artm And if you read it it says among other things that one should *not* just use some value to denote uninitialized state and that the initialization value should be a valid value. They specifically *don’t* recommend initializing just for initialization’s sake and to hide errors.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen and the bottom line is this: "Flag every uninitialized variable. Don't flag variables of user-defined types with default constructors."

Comment: Damn kind of a bad error on my part, thanks lmao